# MVC Razor: Model with Data Annotations and Tinymce

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tinymce

I am developing a code first system, and i have the next property at the class:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

And in my view:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new {@class="wysiwyg"})
```

I use the class *wysiwyg* for rendering the TinyMCE text box editor. It works fine, the problem is that i can submit the form without filling the field.

Do you know how can i solve the problem? (without using javascript where possible)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery validator plugin in order to stop the field submit. 
With JQuery validators you can delegate the field validation to razor and jquery